# .net core 3.1 sftp upload

Tags: c#, .net-core, sftp

Is it possible to upload files and folders using SFTP in .net core 3.1 using webclient?

We don’t want to use third party plugins like Renci.Ssh, WinSCP etc.

Comment: What's the question? Asking for software recommendations is off topic.

Comment: There isn't, I have used Renci with great success with several STFP services from different vendors and I totally recommend it, it works with UWP too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for SFTP or SCP from .net.

Not sure why you are reluctant to using 3rd party libraries. But if its something which cannot be compromised on, you could look at the possibility of launching external programs as sub-processes to perform the necessary activities. However, I believe this is likely to be limited to certain capabilities only.